# Using iFrames in Phonegap And App Crashes

Tags: android, mobile, iframe, cordova

I have created an app with PhoneGap 2.0.0 for Android on Eclipse but when I try run the application either on an emulator or my phone(*signed application with no errors*) it only shows up the **static html pages**. When I go to a page where I have used **iFrame** to load another webpage into it, it ***simply crashes***.
This is the screen I get on the emulator and the same message is displayed on my phone as well(*SE Xperia X10*)

Screenshot of Emulator with The error :

[image: Img]

After showing the message the app crashes instantly. Please let me know if I need to add any other permissions or add other settings or make any changes for this to function because the iFrame functions properly outside Phonegap on browser(including phone/desktop browsers)

Comment: What do you see in "adb logcat" when there is a crash?

Comment: can you post the application log here?

Answer (score 0):

At least some versions of PhoneGap use an iframe to communicate with the native layer.

I'm most familiar with the iOS version, where there are definite bugs in the browser's support of iframes ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-593 ). I don't know if there is a similar system level issue on android, but there could easily be some part of your code that doesn't expect that second iframe to be there.